# How to read fasta file (multiple records) in python (no biopython allowed

Tags: python, sequence, readfile, fasta

I have just started programming in python. I'm completely stuck on the following.
I have a fasta file with multiple protein sequences. 
Different proteins start with a '>' as in all fasta files. I need these proteins to be in one file exact.So i can't just split the files. But i would like to filter out everything that is not a protein sequence.

So if i have a file like this (it's part of a huge file):

```
>gi|636665534|ref|YP_009028572.1| Asp [Human immunodeficiency virus 1]
MPQTVSCNRCCCASIALSKLFCC
CTIPDNNCLACTVSVIEAAPI
>gi|28872817|ref|NP_057852.2| Vpr [Human immunodeficiency virus 1]
MEQAPEDQGPQ
REPHNEWTLELLEELKNEAVR
HFPRIWLHG
```

I would only like to paste the sequences together like this:

> MPQTVSCNRCCCASIALSKLFCCCTIPDNNCLACTVSVIEAAPIMEQAPEDQGPQREPHNEWTLELLEELKNEAVRHFPRIWLHG

I have only been able to filter out the first one and not the others. Or i have only been able to read the first sequence. I need to read these fasta files for school and make diagrams with matplotlib. Except i keep getting stuck on the reading the fasta files part.

I thought i could just make a code like this

```
items = []
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        read = file.readline()
        items.append(read)
```

But the I noticed that there were \n in between the proteinsequences. So that didn't work...

Like i said I just started so if you could answer in the most simplistic (not necessarily the best) way. So in like beginning python language :)

Answer (score 3):

```
with open("file.fasta") as infile, open("output.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith(">"): continue
        outfile.write(line.strip())
```